# Fastest way to compare SQL server results to XML file

Tags: c#, dictionary, xml-parsing

One of our customers has a web shop that runs a synchronization against their ERP system. Since their warehouse serves both their web shop and their physical stores, it's important that the quantity on hand for each product in the web shop is updated often because they don't want to sell products in the web shops that aren't available in the warehouse.

This is currently solved in the following way:
Every five minutes an XML file is posted from the ERP system to the web shop. The file looks something like this:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <productID>1</productID>
    <stock>20</stock>
  </product>
  <product>
    <productID>2</productID>
    <stock>3</stock>
  </product>
</products>
```

The XML contains all the thousands of products in the database, regardless if the quantity on hand has changed for the product or not. Reducing this to only the changed products is not an option according to the ERP provider, so we'll need to handle it on our side.

The web shop then processes the XML file and updates the quantity on hand for all the products in the database with a separate transaction for each update. As you probably understand, this is needlessly slow and resource heavy. The database contains thousands of products, and most of the time, none or very few products have actually changed the quantity in stock.

So my thinking is that the best way to do this is by starting by selecting the productID and stock from the database for all products, comparing the results to the XML, and only updating the products where the stock in the database doesn't match the stock in the XML file.

My question is what would be the fastest way to compare the XML to the result from the database? Reading the XML into memory, looping over the result set from the database and then using XPath on the XML to get the stock value from each product? First converting the XML into a dictionary and then using that for the lookup?

Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: Does the ERP provider have the ability to make the last modified time available in the XML?

Comment: That should be technically possible, but they seem to be unwilling to do much work, so it looks like we're forced to work with what we've got.

Comment: Okay...I had hopes that the data was already there (it frequently is).   If you confirm it's not there, I have a different answer in mind that i've used in the past for other less-complex problems.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid unnecessary importing of the file is to generate a hash code from the file. Before you import the next time you generate the hash code again and compare it against the old one, if they are the same you do not import anything.

```
using(var stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\temp\\file.xml"))
using(var sha = new SHA1Managed())
{
    var hashCode = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
}
```

If the hashed do not match read the database into a dictionary and when you parse the XML file compare it against it. Update the database accordingly. You can even update the dictionary and keep it around (maybe in a static variable) to the next time you need to import, that way you avoid having to fill it from the database all the time.

Comment: That's a great idea for when no products have been updated, but it still leaves the problem of when only a few products have been updated.

Comment: @PetterBrodin yes, added some more info on that.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you assume that reading from the database, possibly followed by a write, will be faster then writing directly? Do not SELECT from the database, there is no need to transport the data from the database server to your web or application server.

For every product item in your XML, just execute

```
UPDATE tablename SET stock = @stock WHERE productID = @productID AND stock <> @stock
```

To increase performance, do not start a transaction for every row, but batch them, for example 10 updates per transaction. You do not have to worry about recoverability anyway. In case of a crash, just process the entire file again from the beginning.

On the input side, the fastest way to read the XML is to read it using an XmlReader, and perform the database updates as you read. Do not read the entire XML into memory before starting to update the database.

Comment: I figured that doing thousands of those queries would be unnecessarily slow as it still needs an index seek for each product, but it would be a very easy fix to improve performance drastically.

Comment: True, but those seeks will almost certainly happen in RAM (cache), and not trigger any IO. In my experience, important things to optimize include 1) number of roundtrips between servers, 2) total amount of bytes send/received between servers and 3) total number of page reads/writes on disk. To reduce 1), use batching. To reduce 2) avoid select followed by update, if the data send by the update is the same as the data selected. You could even use a sproc with a short name to avoid sending the SQL text. 3) can be reduced by batching. Point is: those index seeks in RAM aren't the bottleneck.

Comment: Good points.

I've dug a bit into performance now, and selecting stock and productid from the database takes less than 100 ms + the time it takes to transfer the data from the database server. A quick test shows that the update check takes around 15 milliseconds to perform, which multiplied by thousands adds up to a bit.

Looking at the actual execution plan, there's a clustered index update that takes up 86% of the cost even when the row isn't updated (actual number of rows affected: 0), which seems weird to me. Is there something I'm not doing right there?

Comment: "which multiplied by thousands adds up to a bit" -> yes, but caching implies that you should not simply multiply. The first update will be a lot slower that the second one. "a clustered index update that takes up 86% of the cost" -> of course, but 86% of no IO is still no IO.

Comment: "100 ms + the time it takes to transfer the data from the database server" -> + the CPU time and memory and search processing on the client. How would yu search in there? Probably build an index (dictionary), which takes time and memory. Don't blindly assume that you middle tier index lookup will be faster that SQL Server's index lookup. Only way to know is measuring total execution time.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I'll look into doing that.  


One question about the execution plan, though: doesn't the actual execution plan mean what SQL server actually spent time doing, or is there an element of estimation going on there as well?  


I guess it's the latter, and I just misunderstood how to read the execution plan.